# cfschedule: Fire onError function if url cannot be found

Tags: coldfusion, eventhandler

We have ColdFusion tasks defined like this:

```
<cfschedule
    action="update"
    task="Test"
    operation="HTTPRequest"
    url="#path.getFileFolder()#tasks/test.cfm"
    startDate="#now()#"
    startTime="00:00"
    interval="daily"
    resolveURL="no"
    publish="yes"
    file="test.txt"
    path="#path.getLogFolder#"
    eventHandler="tasks.eventHandler"
    onException="invokeHandler">
```

The `onError` function in the `eventHandler` looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="onError" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="context" type="struct" required="false" />
    <cfscript>
        var slackHookURL = 'urlToOurSlackErrorChannel';
        var slackMessage = 'ourSlackMessage';
    </cfscript>

    <cftry>
        <cfhttp url="#slackHookURL#" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
            <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#slackMessage#" />
        </cfhttp>
        <cfcatch></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

We had the problem that after a server switch our `config` file missed a `/` in the file folder path. So the url referenced in all of our tasks pointed to something like `https://ourPagetasks/test.cfm` instead of `https://ourPage/tasks/test.cfm`. The `onError` function hasn't been fired. We just "accidentally" stumbled upon all our tasks not having been executed ever since.

In the `test.txt` log file however we found the message "Connection timeout". Shouldn't the `onError` function warn us if that happens? Or is there any workaround so I can check the text that's about to be written to the log file? The `onTaskEnd` function of the `eventHandler` is only allowed to have the parameter `context` which tells me nothing about what's going to be logged.

I hope I explained my problem somehow understandable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your CFC defined in the `eventHandler` attribute implementing `CFIDE.scheduler.ITaskEventHandler`? The docs mention _The CFC must be implementing CFIDE.scheduler.ITaskEventHandler._

Comment: @Miguel-F yes it's implementing `CFIDE.scheduler.ITaskEventHandler`. I tried adding an additional parameter to the `onTaskEnd` function but then it threw an error that the `eventHandler` couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to implement a workaround. In our `scheduledTasks.cfm` I added the following lines at the end to check if any of the `urls` are invalid:

```
<!--- Check if the tasks are defined correctly --->
<cfschedule action="list" mode="server" result="tasks" />
<cfloop query="tasks">
    <cfhttp method="head" url="#tasks.URL#" />
    <cfif len(cfhttp.errorDetail)>
        <cfscript>
            slackHookURL = 'urlToOurSlackErrorChannel';
            slackMessage = 'ourSlackMessage';
        </cfscript>

        <cftry>
            <cfhttp url="#slackHookURL#" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
                <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
                <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#slackMessage#" />
            </cfhttp>
            <cfcatch></cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```